# Retain one element and refresh another on drawing on a picturebox control?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to draw a continous line on a picturebox and also a cross located at the cursor. How can it be done to paint the cursor only at the mouse position (and clear it on the next move) and retain the line?

Comment: Just draw the "continuous" line and the crosshairs in the Paint() event of the PictureBox.  In the MouseMove() event call Refresh().

Comment: I think that won't work. Imagine you draw a line in MS Paint. And while you draw a 'mouse placeholder' (e.g. on horizontal and one vertikal line für measuring the cursor position related to the image corner line -> ruler) is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to give you an idea of how to approach this...

Add a PictureBox to a Form.  Run it and click and drag in the PictureBox:

[image: Squiggle Example]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Point cursor;
    Point lastPoint;
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath curPath = null;
    private List<System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath> paths = new List<System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseDown);
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseMove);
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint);
    }

    void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp in paths)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, gp);
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(cursor.X, 0), new Point(cursor.X, pictureBox1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, cursor.Y), new Point(pictureBox1.Width, cursor.Y));
    }

    void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            curPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
            paths.Add(curPath);
        }
    }

    void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        cursor = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point newPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            curPath.AddLine(lastPoint, newPoint);
            lastPoint = newPoint;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: This one is exactly what I wanted to do.